# Why poudriere creates a pair of jails with and without IP addresses

Tags: freebsd, jail

While testing a port using [poudriere](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-poudriere.html) with something like this:

```
poudriere testport -v -j 11amd64 -p custom www/go-www
```

I got this error:

```
!!! build failure encountered !!!               
[00:00:06] ====>> Error: Build failed in phase: fetch
```

For some reason, the package can't be found/downloaded, therefore in my try to check if there was an issue with the jails resolver, I listed the existing [jails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail) by  doing a `jls` - I got this output that caught my attention:

```
>  jls
   JID  IP Address      Hostname                      Path
   363  127.0.0.1       11amd64-custom                /usr/local/poudriere/data/.m/11amd64-custom/ref
   364                  11amd64-custom                /usr/local/poudriere/data/.m/11amd64-custom/ref
   365  127.0.0.1       11amd64-custom-job-02         /usr/local/poudriere/data/.m/11amd64-custom/02
   366                  11amd64-custom-job-02         /usr/local/poudriere/data/.m/11amd64-custom/02
   367  127.0.0.1       11amd64-custom-job-01         /usr/local/poudriere/data/.m/11amd64-custom/01
   368                  11amd64-custom-job-01         /usr/local/poudriere/data/.m/11amd64-custom/01
   369  127.0.0.1       11amd64-custom-job-03         /usr/local/poudriere/data/.m/11amd64-custom/03
   370                  11amd64-custom-job-03         /usr/local/poudriere/data/.m/11amd64-custom/03
```

The thing that I notice is that if I enter to a jail with no IP address assigned `jexec 364` I do can ping/fetch any host, for example, but if I enter to a jail with an IP address `jexec 363`, in this case `127.0.0.1` I can't ping/resolve:

```
ping: sendto: Can't assign requested address
```

Therefore I would like to know what is the idea of creating a pair of jails, one with IP (no routable) and another whitout IP (routable), what is the logic behind?

Just in case this is the configuration I am using for poudriere `/usr/local/etc/poudriere.conf`:

```
ZPOOL=tank
ZROOTFS=/poudriere
FREEBSD_HOST=https://download.FreeBSD.org
RESOLV_CONF=/etc/resolv.conf
BASEFS=/usr/local/poudriere
POUDRIERE_DATA=${BASEFS}/data
USE_PORTLINT=no
USE_TMPFS=yes
DISTFILES_CACHE=/usr/ports/distfiles
CHECK_CHANGED_OPTIONS=verbose
CHECK_CHANGED_DEPS=yes
PKG_REPO_SIGNING_KEY=/usr/local/etc/ssl/keys/pkg.key
CCACHE_DIR=/var/cache/ccache
NOLINUX=yes
```

**UPDATE**

To fix the problem I entered in interactive mode - notice the `-i`:

```
poudriere testport -v -i -j 11amd64 -p custom www/go-www
```

then:

```
cd /usr/ports/www/go-www/; make
```

That fetched the packages and I just copy them to `/usr/ports/distfiles/`

Then again:

```
poudriere testport -v -j 11amd64 -p custom www/go-www
```

That was an ugly hack but the main problem was a bad line in the [Makefile](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-ports/blob/master/www/go-www/Makefile) that was duplicating content:

```
 GH_ACCOUNT=    nbari:DEFAULT,www
```

Should be:

```
 GH_ACCOUNT=    nbari:DEFAULT
```

But still wondering why the pair of jails is created with and without IP.

Comment: @kdhp yes but no idea why the `-i` makes the difference, I will create an issue on GitHub also maybe a bug

Comment: Did the ports that `www/go-www` depends on fetch & build?  The build error needs more context.

Comment: I do need to fetch the sources and build but the `make` process is working this is the patch just in case https://bz-attachments.freebsd.org/attachment.cgi?id=186748

Comment: If works if the duplicate entry is removed from `distinfo`.

Comment: I added an explanation for the fetch error, and a remedy.  It could be classified as a usability bug for not producing a clear error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`poudriere(8)` preforms preforms the stages that do not need networking is a more restrictive jail, for added security.  [Previously](https://github.com/freebsd/poudriere/commit/7e457d7068c92e31bd276486d06039ec16606bb7) the jails were restarted with, or without, networking capabilities, now two separate jails are kept throughout the process to reduce complexity.

The jail with the listed IP address is explicitly set to a loopback address, and the one without inherits it networking from the host:

```
: ${LOIP6:=::1}
: ${LOIP4:=127.0.0.1}
case $IPS in
01)
        localipargs="ip6.addr=${LOIP6}"
        ipargs="ip6=inherit"
        ;;
10)
        localipargs="ip4.addr=${LOIP4}"
        ipargs="ip4=inherit"
        ;;
11)
        localipargs="ip4.addr=${LOIP4} ip6.addr=${LOIP6}"
        ipargs="ip4=inherit ip6=inherit"
        ;;
esac

...

jstart() {
        local name network

        network="${localipargs}"

        [ "${RESTRICT_NETWORKING}" = "yes" ] || network="${ipargs}"

        _my_name name
        jail -c persist name=${name} \
                path=${MASTERMNT}${MY_JOBID+/../${MY_JOBID}} \
                host.hostname=${BUILDER_HOSTNAME-${name}} \
                ${network} ${JAIL_PARAMS} \
                allow.socket_af allow.raw_sockets allow.chflags allow.sysvipc
        jail -c persist name=${name}-n \
                path=${MASTERMNT}${MY_JOBID+/../${MY_JOBID}} \
                host.hostname=${BUILDER_HOSTNAME-${name}} \
                ${ipargs} ${JAIL_PARAMS} \
                allow.socket_af allow.raw_sockets allow.chflags allow.sysvipc
}
```

---

The fetch error seems to be because of the duplicate entries in the new `distfile` (two entries for `nbari-www-1.1.1_GH0.tar.gz`).  The error line
in your log file starts with `fetch: 4211`, 4211 being the size of the duplicate entry.

The entry in question is being added twice because of the groups specified with `GH_ACCOUNT`, `DEFAUT` adds the `PORTNAME` (`www`), and `www` adds itself.